# Google Storage creating Signed Urls with your own program rather using google cloud libraries

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, pre-signed-url, signed-url

Google Storage allows using custom created signed urls as advertised in the following link : [V4 signing process with your own program](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually)

What is the reason for that ? Will this be faster than requesting a signed url for each of the objects in google storage ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose is to provide a way to sign URL without needing one of the provided Cloud Storage client libraries.  Since it's a rest API, you can call it from any language you want that can make HTTP requests and perform RSA signatures.  From that page you linked:

> This page describes an algorithm for implementing the V4 signing process so that you can create Cloud Storage RSA key signed URLs in your own workflow, **using a programming language of your choice.**

The example shown is in python, but the text makes it clear that:

> The sample uses the Python programming language, **but does not use the Cloud Storage Client Libraries**:

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Doug. For instance, when creating 100 signed-urls at a time, this can be a real bottleneck for the application. What would be the benefit of signing custom urls, will this be any faster than relying on Cloud Storage Client Libraries ?

Comment: I don't think there would be any, as I imagine they are all just calling the same API.  I suggest benchmarking it yourself to gain data.